# Dryer vent: proximity to electrical wires

Tags: hvac, dryer, vent

We recently moved into a new home, and the ductwork for the (as yet uninstalled) LG DLE3500W electric dryer is the flexible foil type. To avoid an additional bend in the duct, it runs across some electric wires. Assuming we eliminate the slack shown in the picture below, my questions are:

1. Is foil ductwork okay here, or should I replace it with aluminum ducts?
2. Is it okay for a dryer duct to be this close to electrical wiring, or does it need to be re-routed?

[image]

Comment: How long is the dryer duct?

Comment: That seems like a _very_ long duct.  Counting boards it looks like it's at least 4 or 5 feet long, and maybe 10+?  Not sure that's a good idea.  Also curious how it's where it is - in the ceiling of the basement - is the dryer in the basement (and thus this is much longer, as it goes up five or six feet first) or above it?

Answer (score 9):

In my personal opinion, this type of duct is NEVER a good idea for a dryer vent.

Lint sticks to the inside much more than smooth metal.

It's virtually impossible to clean effectively, without damaging the duct.

How long do you think it will last (contain the flames) when the lint inside catches fire?

Solid, smooth metal is the only sensible choice. Making it as short as physically possible is also sensible. Long, complex dryer vents are just an invitation to problems.

Having it touching the wires is likely to overheat that portion of the wires each time the dryer operates, so at minimum providing some insulation between the two would be better.

Comment: I was going to answer with our last paragraph but you edited your answer. I  totally agree.  I have a two foot section of that flex , dryer to rigid, and clean it every year.+